# OCI Kubernetes Cluster (OKE) - node.cloudprovider.kubernetes.io/uninitialized=true:NoSchedule

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

**Issue Description:**

Cluster, node pool was successfully created however, node was tainted with node.cloudprovider.kubernetes.io/uninitialized=true:NoSchedule. Hence no application pods was schedule to any node available.

**Cluster Details:**

```
Kubernetes version: v1.23.4
Kubernetes API endpoint subnet: Public-subnet (public facing)
Service LB subnet 1: Public-subnet (public facing)
```

**Node Details:**

```
Network Type: FLANNEL_OVERLAY
Worker node subnet: Application-Subnet (private facing)
Shape: VM.Standard.A1.Flex
Image name: Oracle-Linux-7.9-aarch64-2022.06.30-0-OKE-1.23.4-392
```

Any possible fix to this? Already added NAT to the private subnet route table to have egress connection. Tried opening the NACLs, Security List (to isolate if this is a network issue)